# How can i get the parent script's name?

Tags: bash, path, parent

I have a bash-script that is called by another script or process.
So script/process A calls script B.

I have access to change script B and i want to know the name (and path, if possible) of the script/process A.

What do i need to write into script B to echo/outout me the name of script/process A?

pstree is no option for me :/

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the parent pid

```
echo "$PPID"
```

To get parent process path you can parse the full cmd

```
ps -o command= -p "$PPID" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Another option on most unix-based systems

```
awk '{print $1}'  /proc/"$PPID"/cmdline
```

Comment: Thanks, your 3rd line was perfect for me :)